# Assessing Significance in Neural Networks

Tags: statistical-significance, bootstrap, neural-networks

I'm trying to determine statistical significance of inputs on the dependent variable using neural networks. I'm trying to test the null hypothesis that the partial derivatives are equal to zero. I found a method called Bootstrapping but it requires to retrain the neural network a 1000 times. Is there any alternative less time consuming solution to this problem?